# Honeypot Configuration - Alerting with Mandrill

Tags: honeypot

Has anyone connected the OpenCanary Honeypot Correlator to Mandrill? There is a section of the opencanary_correlator.conf file that allows for the Mandrill API key but for no other configuration. How does one configure the alerting through Mandrill work properly?  I have not installed the Mandrill Python API client as the OpenCanary config file includes some of the same information, which implies a built-in connector somehow.